# page fault while executing machine instruction

Tags: operating-systems, paging

A process executing machine instruction Y right after machine instruction x.On executing x It causes a page fault. what is the next instruction that is executed immediately on restarting the process. ? assume that instead of page fault the process receives timer interrupt while executing x. what is the next instruction that is executed immediately on restarting the process.

Comment: Hello! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question may be voted to be closed / downvoted. You may also want to check out [these hints](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98), or use the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a problem dump.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to consult the manuals of the manufacturer of the processor for details like this. Different processors will behave in different ways.

On a modern processor, "executing instruction y after instruction x" usually makes little sense. Instructions are executed simultaneously, out of order, and so on. What the processor and operating system hopefully guarantee that either the total observable behaviour will be as if the page had been present (except for some delay), or the process is killed, or a higher level signal is sent to the process informing it that the page isn't there *and cannot be acquired*.

And I remember that on a 68020 processor a single instruction could create up to 11 (eleven) page faults...

Answer (score -1):

Regarding page fault I found these on the internet at 2 different sources :)
*The process is then restarted at the machine instruction where the memory fault occurred. 
*If instructions are idempotent, just restart the faulting instruction (hardware saves instruction address during page fault).

So it seems that it again tries to execute X.

Comment: If you rely on online sources, you should cite them. If you're not sure about your answer, perhaps you should wait for a more knowledgeable person.